# Как решить проблему с "HEAD detached from origin/master"

Tags: git

Как получилось такое состояние — не знаю. Вобщем, поработал, сделал пару коммитов локально, все OK. Решил отправить на сервер,

```
> git push origin
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

    git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

Что за `<name-of-remote-branch>` — один git ведает...

Смотрю состояние:

```
> git status
HEAD detached from origin/master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        VCRelease64/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Ну, Untracked files меня совсем не интересуют.

Поискал в интернете — совет "сделай git checkout origin/master". Хорошо, что сохранил все полностью на всякий случай — выбросило два последних коммита в... вобщем, их не осталось. Восстановил.

В gitk выглядит так, как на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: что нужно сделать, чтоб вернуть в нормальное состояние и ничего не потерять? Как вариант, я уже думал — попробовать все с сервера опять стянуть, как новый проект, переписать в него изменения и работать, но как-то неспортивно :)

Пояснять, как работает git, не уверен, что нужно — все равно не понимаю совершенно, сколько ни читал, если б начальство не требовало, я б им и не заморачивался. Так что просто — как вырулить в этой ситуации и двумя словами, почему именно так (вдруг пойму). Как я понимаю, мне не HEAD куда-то приаттачить надо, а origin/master к нему подтянуть, нет?

P.S. Всегда хватало `git commit` и `git push` :)

Comment: Текущее состояние (указатель HEAD указывает на коммит, ака detached head) видимо возникло, потому что перед новыми коммитами был сделан checkout по id коммита. Соответственно после новых коммитов указатель `master` не передвигался. `git branch -f master && git checkout master` переставит указатель `master` на текущий коммит и затем переставит указатель `HEAD` на указатель `master`.

Comment: *"Как получилось такое состояние — не знаю"*  --- вы вместо `git checkout my-branch`  случайно сделали `git checkout origin/my-branch`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да я вроде вообще checkout не делал... reset --hard было, да. А вообще достает, что checkout в старом cvs было, похоже, совсем не то, что в git... :(

Comment: @user7860670 Спасибо! Напишите ответом, чтоб принять. Откровенно, всегда думал, что ветка - просто последовательность коммитов, так что как можно указывать на ветку, а не на коммит — для меня загадочная тайна... А если и можно, то какая между ними разница... Все-таки для меня git — очень запутанная и неочевидная система. Я даже скажу одну крамолу: для меня вообще непонятно, как можно одновременно работать над чем-то одним, без риска нестыковок, даже при внесении изменений в разных файлах. Как статью писать с соавторами — обязательно потом будут нестыковки, надо потом одному переписывать...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Таки вы правы (наполовину) — покопался в истории, был вызов, но только `git checkout origin`. Никаких `my-branch` :) Для cvs это было бы просто восстановлением всех исходников, типа `git reset --hard`, как я понимаю.

Comment: Ветка в гите - это *только* указатель на коммит, а не их цепочка. И это ППЦ какой мутный момент. Я долгое время работал с mercurial, который в целом основан на тех же идеях и имеет сходный функционал, однако в нем ветками являются как раз цепочки коммитов. Достаточно интуитивно и состояния detached head и потери коммитов, когда они не находятся в цепочке, на которую указывает хотя бы один указатель, не возникают в принципе. Причем указатели на коммиты там тоже были, но они назывались закладками. Думая о ветках в гите, как о закладках, с ними несколько проще работать.

Comment: git commit - это добавление одного коммита в цепочку и перемещение текущей закладки. git push - это отправка закладки на сервер (и соотв. новых коммитов из цепочки, на который указывает закладка). и т.п. *"для меня вообще непонятно, как можно одновременно работать над чем-то одним, без риска нестыковок"* - так а git совершенно не избавляет от риска нестыковок. Это проблема организации работы. git скорее инструмент для их обнаружения и разруливания.

Comment: @user7860670 Ну, лично для меня он выполняет две функции — ностальгическую (типа, посмотреть, в каком виде все это было пару лет назад...) и откатно-техническую (блин, что-то вконец зашился... вобщем, верни все, как было с утра... — так что я `reset` кроме как с `--hard` и не использую). Один раз как-то попробовал было "ответвить" работу над отдельной функциональностью, но в результате запутался куда сильнее, чем если бы работал, как обычно... Ладно, это уже мои заморочки, еще раз спасибо, что выручили своими таинственными командами :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Текущее состояние (указатель `HEAD` указывает на коммит, ака detached head) видимо возникло, потому что перед новыми коммитами был сделан `checkout` по id коммита. Соответственно после новых коммитов указатель `master` не передвигался.

`git branch -f master && git checkout master`
переставит указатель `master` на текущий коммит и затем переставит указатель `HEAD` на указатель master.